# What are the intuitions about matrix algebra operations?

Tags: matrices, intuition, matrix-decomposition

In my current data analysis problem I am using models with complicated penalty structure that is a result of operations on some matrix $Q$.

I do know definitions of basic matrix operations:

- $Q^T$
- $Q^{-1}$
- $QQ^T$

but I feel I lack **intuitions** / **imagination** what is going on with $Q$ when undergoes these operations.

Eventually, I would like to *get the feeling* what is done here:

- $Q_{res} = Q^T(QQ^T)^{-1}Q$
- $W_{res} = W (a(I-Q_{res}) + b Q_{res})^{-1}$

for some

- $Q: dim(Q)=[n_1,n_2]$, a subspace containing some structure relevant to variables (columns) of $W$,
- $W: dim(W)=[n_3, n_2]$, subjects' (rows) observations of some variables (columns) of which (variables) we have some knowledge of its structure.

I kindly ask for some explanation / good material references.

Comment: I think the only intuition that will help you will be connected to your data analysis problem. Find the first few places in that problem where a model uses a matrix calculation and try to understand what is happening in that context. Then ask a focused question here (or on cross validated http://stats.stackexchange.com/ ) if you are stuck.

Comment: Assuming that the columns of $Q$ are linearly independent, $Q_{res}$ is the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto the subspace spanned by $Q$’s columns. I’m not sure that you can get to that just from knowing what the individual operations do. $W_{res}$ is pretty much impossible to interpret without more information about $W$ and $R$ and how they fit into your problem. As @EthanBolker says, it’s probably best to start with what’s going on in the model instead of trying to understand the matrix calculations from the ground up.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I edited my question by adding some additional information about the context. I know by definition what $Q_{res}$ is, I just struggle to understand that by these chain of operations ($Q^T(QQ^T)^{-1}Q$) I obtain that matrix of the orthogonal projection onto the subspace spanned by $Q$’s columns. I think I lack some very basic  example showing intermediate results of these operations.